# trouble with rails includes query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am at a loss with this, and cannot figure it out for the life of me :|

Below,  `@selected_posts` represents a query on `Posts`. I want to query sort users that have posts in `@selected_posts`. Currently, with the code below I am returning a proper user list of ALL users in the users table. I would get Mike, 5 - Joe, 3 - John, 0 - Jack, 0 -- the zeros show that it is querying every single user (which is going to be a problem. Any suggestions on how to fix the below code to get it to only query the users that have posts in `@selected_posts`?

```
@posts = user.includes(@selected_posts).map{ |user|

  [user.name, user.posts.count, user.username]

}.sort
```

Thanks to any help, I am in debt to you (you have no idea how crazy this has been driving me)

Comment: need more info on what is in @selected_posts ...

Comment: `@selected_posts = Posts.where(:category => "Baseball")` I have a many to many set up between `Posts` and `Users`

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware that you could put a ActiveRelation inside a includes like that. includes does a left join type of query, perhaps you need to use joins ?

Comment: Why is this many to many? Can a post be made by several users? Seems like this should be: User has_many Posts / Post belongs_to User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I undesrstood, you have models: Post and User. User can have many posts. And your goal is to get all user that have posts. You can do it in different ways. For example: define scope in User model

```
scope :with_posts, -> { joins(:posts) }
```

Comment: Well, close. I'm trying to get all users that have posts inside of my `@selected_posts` query which is `@selected_posts = Posts.where(:category => "Baseball")` I want to query the number of posts each user has in that category. My trouble is, my code in the OP is querying every single user in the database, and not just the users that have posts inside of `@selected_posts`

Comment: As you can understand, with alot of users, querying every user against a category or group of objects can be taxing.

Comment: so try: `@selected_posts = Posts.where(:category => "Baseball")` and then: `User.with_posts(@selected_posts)` and rewrite scope to `scope lambda {|post_query| joins(:posts).post_query}`. I think it should work. Anyway? now you have on more guess :). Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it yet, but wouldn't this be more on the line of:

```
@users = User.joins(:posts).where(:posts => {:category => "Baseball"})
```

Just for completeness and because I like the result:

```
@users = Post.where(:category => "one").group(:user).count
```

would give you an OrderedHash with users as key and postcount as value.

Comment: This is along the line of what I'm looking for. However, the 'Baseball' was just an example. What I'm really looking for is usage of a group of posts in `@selected_posts`. Any ideas on how to do that? Thanks so much!

Comment: @masedesign: I'm not sure if I understand 100% what you want to do. Do you need to have first to query `@selected_posts` and use the results or is it ok to put everything into one query and you mainly want to add grouping and say count the number of posts (with certain additional conditions like category)?